# Read URL to string Java with cookies

Tags: java, url, cookies

I need to read from an URL to String, and this is not a problem, but some sites demand for cookies to be enabled to provide content. So I need a way to get a content even if the cookies need to be accepted? 
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may give it a try to Apache's HTTPClient:  http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/

It has support a lot of things. I don't remember if cookies are included, but I bet it does.

**EDIT**

It does :)

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html

Answer (score 0):

`java.net` supports cookies through `HttpCookie`.